# Oracle installation error because of previous installation

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I try to installe the oracle ex universal version. Before this i have removed all oracle instances from the registry. But below error comes when i try to proceed with the new installation.

> Installer has detected Oracle Database 10g Express (Western European)
>   Edition on this system. ORacle Database 10g Express (Universal)
>   edition and oracle 1g Express (Western European) edition can not
>   coexist

How to remove remaining installation of Oracle Database 10g Express previously installed version in this?

Comment: Please read this thread on the Oracle TechNet forums: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/850216

Comment: How did you remove other Oracle instances? Try running universal installer and try to remover any existing Oracle instances.

Comment: enter `dbca` on the command prompt and follow the wizard

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar problem and this worked for me.

1. Open Task Manager and check whether you have a service named "OracleServiceXE" running. If true, follow the following steps:
2. Run command prompt as administrator.
3. Execute the following command:

   `C:\> sc delete OracleServiceXE`
4. Now run the task manager again and check whether the service still exists or not.
5. Restart your PC and then try reinstalling the software.

Hope this works.